Can I request to see the content of some deleted comments?
A week ago I asked in MSE a question and got an answer to my initial problem and some follow up questions in comments by a user, who unfortunately a few days ago decided to delete these highly informative comments.
That's sad, because these highly insightful elaborations answered my problem and unfortunately I missed to record them on my pc. Moreover I'm pretty sure that other users facing similar problems could profit from them.
So my question is if there are possibilities to get access to these deleted comments.
For instance, do I have the right to demand from moderators - who presumably should have the permissions to access deleted comments - to get a copy of deleted comments? If not, why does this violate some policy of this site?
Which possibilities do I else have?
[Note that I not ask to redelete the deleted comments in the public thread as this would violate the rights of the user's interest who from certain reasons not known to me decided to delete them.]
#UPDATE/REPORT OF A TRAGEDY: Up to now I tried to draw moderator's attention by putting flag on the question and explaining the issue as I wrote before.
My suggestion was that for the case that the moderators are not allowed to redelete deleted comments for the public thread, (...that's reasonable as clearly the decision of user who deleted it should be respected) if it is possible to send to me (as requester, who was actively involved in discussion) a copy of the deleted comments to my mail account associated with my SE account.
But seemingly my first flag/request got completely misunderstood: The flag was by mod Declined with "argument" that "They don't give out user's emails here.".
Sure, about this I clearly agree. But I nowhere asked for email adress of some user. It seems that I got completely misunderstood, as I not asked to get some email of some user, but instead to obtain a copy of deleted comments on my mail associated with account, so especially known to mods. This appeared for me to be a reasonable suggestion.
So I tried to make a new request explaining this obvious confusion of my previous request attached to the flag.
Now it was again declined with remark that I already made an identical request before.
Seriously, that's a bad joke.
So my first flaged request got declined because it was obviously simply completely misunderstood, and second one - which repeated my concern and elaborated why the first one was misunderstood - got declined because it was "identical to first", which was already declined. Seriously?
A question to talented dramaturgs, how to bring this tragedy to a reconciliatory end? (...sorry for theatricality)

As written, this is a request for support (how can I currently do something/how does this work/please do something that's already possible), not a feature request (please change something about the site).

If you recall the name of the user in question, you could ask them to recreate those comments.  Beyond that...well, just speaking personally, if I delete a comment of mine I expect it to stay deleted.  Unlike the answers, comments are ephemeral by nature.

@lulu: But how can I contact the moderators with this concern in order toask them to restore them? Tried to flag thequestion itself yesterday in order to draw maderators attention and indicated also the name, but till now got no response. About personal issue: Yes in general I agree with you that there surely should be a lot of reasons why someone who deleted own comments has reasons to do it.But in my case I just not understand this action: The deleted comments included just qualitatively very informative elaborations adressing my questions; there was nothing what is justifiable to be deteted

As I say, in my (personal) opinion, the comments should not be restored unless the original writer restores them.  Again, if you recall the user name, you could ask them.  Should say:  I don't even know if they are saved.  I do not believe that I have access to my own comments after they are deleted, for example.

@lulu: Yes, but how can I ask the mods about this? Is there a mail adress for such kind of issues available to contact the moderators? (haven't found it)

You can flag the question to ask for a moderator's attention.

Can you ask? Sure. I've provided such information to users in the past on a different site of the SE network. However, your questions states whether you can demand this from moderators. And honestly I don't know the answer to that. I'd think not, deleted content is only made available again on basis of exceptions or there would be no point in removing it.

@Mast: Thanks, think my "demand phrasing" is a bad - even "rude" -wording. The focus was more precisley on if such providing the deleted comments would a priori violating certain site policy, and so far I not see one.

Moderators can see deleted comments.  However, I don't know where the other moderators stand on the issue of sharing them; I'm relatively new.  They were indeed deleted by that user.

@Shaun: On other SE networks that seems to be ok...

@Shaun You have tools to communicate with the other mods and get an answer, right?

A possible compromise:  As it seems undesirable to have deleted comments published (even to a single user) without consent, perhaps a moderator could ping the user in question and inquire.  If that user does not mind, then the comments could be released (again, possibly only to a single user).  If the user objects (or is silent) then perhaps that settles the matter.

@lulu: Totally agree, great suggestion!

Comments are ephemeral, by design.  A user is permitted to delete their own comments, for whatever reason.  As a moderator, I am in favor of respecting the privacy of the person who posted those comments, and chose to delete them.  As this meta question seems to be a call for moderator action, rather than an actual question about how the site works, I will be closing it now.

The long-term solution is to explain users how comments work and that in particular they are not used for answering the problem.

Comments are disposable: unlike posts, there's no public revision history, and they can be deleted without warning by their authors, by moderators, and in response to flags.

See also Dealing with answers in comments. for the reasons why answers should be posted as answers. When you see an answer in a comment, you can ask the user to actually write an answer. This will hopefully prevent the issue presented here from happening again in the future. If you have sufficient reputation, deleted answers are still visible.
For the solution of your specific problem, the following paragraph from the guidelines is relevant:

When can comments be undeleted?
Only moderators can undelete comments. When looking at deleted comments on a post, moderators are not provided with a button to undelete the comment unless the comment was deleted by a current moderator. Moderators can undelete any comment from the page listing all of the specific user's comments, regardless of who deleted the comment.

This means that it is technically possible for moderators to undelete any comment. The guidelines do not say, though, when this happens. But that the UI on the question itself only allows to delete comments written by moderators, suggests that comments by normal users should only be undeleted in special occasions and that usually their decision for deleting their comment is respected. Personally, I would feel quite uncomfortable when I decide to delete a comment of mine (for good reasons, in this scenario) and then later a moderator overrides my decision.

About the last paragraph: I agree that in general it is reasonable to expect that the decision to a user to delet her/his commets should finally of course respected. It's indeed reasonable that that one user may would feel quite uncomfortable when after deciding to delete a comment later a moderator undeletes and makes it available for publicity.

I was thinking in direction @lulu suggested in one of the comments above: For example one could firstly ask the user who decided to delete the question and make an inquire that somebody anounced interest to see the deleted comment again. If that user does not mind, then the comments could be released (at least, possibly only to user who made the request for it). I think, that this would be a good compomise, even though I agree with you on that deleting comments should generally not be treated on same track like deleting answers, but sometimes such deleting comments deprive us from

really good math from which the community could profit. And, as I guess, such concrete requests to make deleted comments available again to (at least) single user who made the request deleted comments happen not very often in the network and so deserve to be decided by mods from case to case.
